# Flow Types: Field between square brackets

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, flowtype

In Flow Types :

```
export type GroupType = {
  options: OptionsType,
  [string]: any,
};
```

**What does `[string]: any` mean ?**

Edit :

Thank you for your responses.

**How do I must understand this piece of code ?**

```
import type { GroupType } from './types';
const formatGroupLabel = (group: GroupType): string => group.label;
```

For me `formatGroupLabel` is a function that takes `group` as a parameter and return `group.label`. But I don't understand why there is `: string` in front of `(group: GroupType)`. May be there is no link with my first question.

Comment: Updated my answer, though I think that should had been a different question.

Answer (score 4):

It's an index property, it means that if you try to get a property whose key is a `string`, the value will be of type `any`. [Documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-objects-as-maps)

It's quite common to use it like this to avoid confusion (but both ways are valid):

```
export type GroupType = {
  options: OptionsType,
  [index: string]: any
};
```

So you can use it for objects like:

```js
/** @type {GroupType} */
var type = {
  options: {},
  a: 1,
  b: "foo",
  c: function fooBar() {}
};

console.log(typeof type["a"]);
console.log(typeof type["b"]);
console.log(typeof type["c"]);
```

For the second part, `const formatGroupLabel = (group: GroupType): string => group.label;` is a function that accepts a `GroupType`, returns a `string` and it's body is `return group.label`. It would have the following format in JavaScript:

```js
/** @type {(group: GroupType) => string} */
const formatGroupLabel = (group) => {
  return group.label;
};
```